# HTTP ResponseCode 400

Tags: java, http

I'm using this link that I've changed a little in order to get convert adress to GeoCodes :http://julien.gunnm.org/geek/programming/2015/09/13/how-to-get-geocoding-information-in-java-without-google-maps-api/

I don't understand for some requests I get 400 responseCode and for some i don't have any issue.(I tried these requests and they work fine for me).

For example:

```
    private String getRequest(String url) throws Exception {
 url=http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search=42+Avenue+Foch,+Saint+Maur+Des+Fossés+France&format=json&addressdetails=1
        final URL obj = new URL(url);
        final HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(url.length()));

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream is ;
        if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            is = con.getInputStream();
        } else {
            is = con.getErrorStream();
        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        return response.toString();
    }
```